# Inner Parser: Scanner Error: Numeric Argument to substrString

Tags: kframework

I'm working on [lesson 10](https://kframework.org/k-distribution/k-tutorial/1_basic/10_strings/) of the K introduction. Can't figure out an error I'm getting. I have the file `lesson-10.k` with the following contents (simplified for now to demonstrate the error):

```
module LESSON-10
  imports STRING

  syntax String ::= nonsentence(String) [function]
  rule nonsentence(S) => substrString(S, 0, 5)
  rule nonsentence(_) => " ." [owise]
endmodule
```

When I try to compile it as follows:

```
kompile lesson-10.k
```

I get this error - compiler seems to be flagging the argument `0` to `substrString` as unexpected:

```
[Error] Inner Parser: Scanner error: unexpected character sequence '0'.
        Source(/home/bhandalc/k/lesson-10/lesson-10.k)
        Location(5,42,5,43)
[Error] Compiler: Had 1 parsing errors.
```

I'm working on WSL with Ubuntu focal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Ah I got it. I wasn't importing `INT` so it didn't know what `0` was. Fixed code:

```
module LESSON-10
  imports INT
  imports STRING

  syntax String ::= nonsentence(String) [function]
  rule nonsentence(S) => substrString(S, 0, 5)
  rule nonsentence(_) => " ." [owise]
endmodule
```

---

I was initially still a little bit confused by this because I thought "Surely `STRING` needs `INT` to define the substring function in the first place?"

Then I saw this in the [K User Manual](https://kframework.org/USER_MANUAL/#module-declaration):

> Imports can be public or private. By default, they are public, which
> means that all the imported syntax can be used by any module that
> imports the module doing the import. However, you can explicitly
> override the visibility of the import with the public or private
> keyword immediately prior to the module name. A module imported
> privately does not export its syntax to modules that import the module
> doing the import.

And indeed, the `INT` import is private in `STRING-COMMON`:

```
module STRING-COMMON
  imports STRING-SYNTAX
  imports private INT
  imports private FLOAT-SYNTAX
  imports private K-EQUAL
  imports private BOOL
```

...And `STRING` itself is built atop `STRING-COMMON`:

```
module STRING
  imports STRING-COMMON
```

So importing `STRING` won't just bring in the `INT` module for you. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer; you should accept it yourself once the requisite time has passed.

Comment: Great thanks Bruce. Will do :)